# How to remove the bottom border of a box with CSS

Tags: css, border

[image]

I have a rectangular `div`, like the one above. I want to remove the bottom border (from C to D) in my `div`. How can I do this?.

Edit: Here is my CSS:

```css
#index-03 {
  position: absolute;
  border: .1px solid #900;
  border-width: .1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #900;
  left: 0px;
  top: 102px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 27px;
}
```

```html
<div id="index-03" 
     style="background-color:limegreen; width:300px; height:75px;">
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean omit it? From where? Where is your code?

Comment: I have given my div a 1px border.I want to drop the 1px border in the length C-D.

Comment: You would need to use border-bottom:none.

Comment: no point using fractional *`.1px`* pixel sizes as those cannot be represented.. use integer values for `px` values.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Just add in: `border-bottom: none;`

```
#index-03 {
    position:absolute;
    border: .1px solid #900;
    border-bottom: none;
    left:0px;
    top:102px;
    width:900px;
    height:27px;
}
```

Comment: For future reference to readers here are [the border properties as defined in the W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-properties)

Comment: Pro tip: Order matters. If you try to set `border-bottom: none;` before the `border: .1px solid #900;` then it won't work.

Comment: @LeviFuller Thanks, you saved me a lot of time !

Comment: Is it possible to make few pixels of the border bottom invisble for a div.

Answer (score 7):

You can either set

```
border-bottom: none;
```

or

```
border-bottom: 0;
```

One sets the `border-style` to `none`.
One sets the `border-width` to `0px`.

```css
div {
  border: 3px solid #900;

  background-color: limegreen; 
  width:  28vw;
  height: 10vw;
  margin:  1vw;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.stylenone {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.widthzero {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
(full border)
</div>
<div class="stylenone">
(style)<br><br>

border-bottom: none;
</div>
<div class="widthzero">
(width)<br><br>
border-bottom: 0;
</div>
```

Side Note:
If you ever have to track down why a border is not showing when you expect it to,
It is also good to know that either of these could be the culprit.
Also verify the `border-color` is not the same as the `background-color`.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to misunderstand the box model - in CSS you provide points for the top and left and then width and height - these are all that are needed for a box to be placed with exact measurements.

The `width` property is what your `C-D` is, but it is also what `A-B` is. If you omit it, the div will not have a defined width and the width will be defined by its contents.

---

Update (following the comments on the question:

Add a [`border-bottom-style: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-bottom-style) to your CSS to remove this style from the bottom only.

Comment: If you have a minute,i would like you to take a look at yahoo.com.At the bottom there,you will find the 'MARKETPLACE' div.How do you think they made that.

Comment: It is just a DIV with a solid border. That DIV is also a container to three more DIVs.

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the width to auto. Then the width of the div will equal 0 if it has no content.

```
width:auto;
```